# K8S ReadinessProbe failed, but not from the pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

When doing a `kubectl describe pods xxxx`, I got in the `Events`

> Warning  Unhealthy  7m5s (x2 over 7m15s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.13.66:8080/manage/info": dial tcp 192.168.13.66:8080: connect: connection refused

But when I logged into the pods `kubectl exec -ti xxx -- /bin/bash`, it seems to work

```
curl localhost:8080/manage/info
{"build":{"version":"yyyy","branch":"UNKNOWN","ciNumber":"yyy","revision":"25ce837","artifact":"artichaud","name":"xxx","time":"2022-06-07T07:25:19.440Z","user":"root", ...."}}
```

As far as I understand, the ReadinessProbe is performed by `kubelet` which runs on each node. So, how could the `kubelet` agent not able to perform the probe, while I can from the pods (or any pods for that matter) ?

Here are the Probes

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /manage/info
    port: http
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 5

readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /manage/info
    port: http
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 5
```

The port (`http`) is already defined

```
containers:
  - name: service
    image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
    imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
    ports:
      - name: http
        containerPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
```

Comment: Is the 8080 port exposed in the pod spec?

Comment: Hmm, not sure actually! 
``` 
Containers:
  service:
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
```

Comment: @w08r you dont actually need to specify the port in the pod spec. Its purely informational.

Comment: I would suggest sharing the probes themselves as yaml

Comment: Probes are added.

Comment: you use http as name in the readiness probe, but from your comment it doesnt look like you have given your port in the spec that name. This doesnt work. Use 8080 as port or name the port in the pod spec.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The port is already defined in the container spec, so I don't think that's the issue, see edit (one more time, sorry).

Comment: I had something like this too one time. It went away after 1 day or so. That said, if your readiness probe and liveness probe are the same, you should remove the readiness probe. Readiness probe has a different purpose. Some apps will even set them self as not ready while doing heavy computations. A failed liveness check will result in pod restart. A failed readiness check will result in the pod being taken off the endpoint list of any service that selects it, so that no traffic through that services is routed to the pod while it's not ready.